# Adding custom buttons to iphone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, button, interface-builder

How can I use a custom button instead of a predefined button object in the interface builder?

Answer (score 2):

If it is a custom subclass of `UIButton`, add a "button" as usual, and in the inspector set the class to be your subclass, and set the type to "custom." If it is a "button-like-view" that is not a subclass of `UIButton`, then add a "custom view" and set its class to be your subclass. When possible, "button-like things" should be subclasses of `UIButton` but this isn't always appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you provide an image in your project to be used as the custom button.You can provide different images based on the "state" of the button. (`Default`, `Higlighted`, `Selected`, `Disabled`)

Other than that it should behave just as a regular `UIButton`.